# Android PdfRenderer class - Too long to render on few PDFs

Tags: android, pdf, long-integer, mask, pdfrenderer

In Android 5.0, Google introduced the PdfRenderer class for rendering PDFs. However, on few PDFs, the rendering is too long (~5 seconds) and I noticed a common point between all of this PDFs: they contain a clipping mask.

When I remove this mask, the rendering works perfectly, but in my Android app, I retrieve the PDF files from a server and they may have this mask.

Does anyone have encountered this problem? I searched a lot before posting this question and unfortunately I didn't find solution.